# can aws config be used to store application specific configuration (other than aws configurations)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, config

as per the amazon documentation, aws config stores aws resource configuration. Can it be used to store the application specific configuration as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS Config doesn't allow you to store configuration information -- it polls the various AWS service APIs and gathers information about the configuration of your AWS resources... which it then stores on your behalf for your later review.

> Config continuously monitors and records your AWS resource configurations and allows you to automate the evaluation of recorded configurations against desired configurations.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/config/

However, there is a service for storing configuration data, called the *AWS¹ Systems Manager Parameter Store.*

> AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store provides secure, hierarchical storage for configuration data management and secrets management. You can store data such as passwords, database strings, and license codes as parameter values. You can store values as plain text or encrypted data.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html

---

¹ Formerly called *EC2 Systems Manager,* this service (which includes optional components in addition to Parameter Store) can also be used independently from EC2.  It is also sometimes referred to as [*SSM*](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/tag/amazon-ec2-simple-systems-manager/).

Comment: does it support xml? as per the documentation, it only supports json/yml.